# QVector<custom class> connection thread cannot queue arguments of type

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, metadata, slots

I have problem.
I have a custom class `BasicSpace`. This class isntt `qobject` (don't have macro) and don't inherit by `qobject`. It is simple class with some data, qtime etc.
I have:

```
connect(connector,SIGNAL(finishedReadData(QVector<BasicSpace>&)),&window,SLOT(updateData(QVector<BasicSpace>&)));
```

I try

```
qRegisterMetaType< QVector<BasicSpace> >("QVector<BasicSpace>");
```

in `main.cpp`.

But Qt still when slot is called take me msg:

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector&'
>   (Make sure 'QVector&' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

My concentration is betwen thread.

My project is advanced, so I try avoid `typedef` solutions with different name, so I don't test it.
Someone can help me?

EDIT
THX Frank. I replace reference to value like QVector, without &. This work but i have doubt. It works but thread connections always copy data, so prabodly without reference data is doubled copy, first time in function and second time betwen thread?

I rhing that is 50% solved. I have working code but main problem - reference value with template type in queued connection is unsolved.

Comment: Don’t pass non-const reference, but either by const reference or by value. I.e. `finishedReadData(QVector<BasicSpace>)`.

Comment: Frank is right. Nevertheless it works for my without problems like you try it. Without any need to register something. Could you please post your slot and signal declarations. Usually one doesn't need to think much about the signal & slot parameters and doesn't need to register that type for most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect a signal and a slot of objects that live in the same thread, the `Qt::DirectConnection` type is used. In this case the slot is executed as a normal function call. You don't have to register your data type via `qRegisterMetaType`, and when you send your data as a reference it is not copied.

When sender and receiver objects do not live in the same thread, the `Qt::QueuedConnection` type is used. Now, when you send some data, it is copied into the event queue, no matter if you send it by value or by reference. Also your data type must be registered using `qRegisterMetaType`.

Here is a simple example that illustrates this behaviour:

```
class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject()
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    }

    MyObject(const MyObject &other)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    }

    ~MyObject()
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    }

};

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

signals:
    void myObjectSignal1(const MyObject &obj);
    void myObjectSignal2(const MyObject &obj);

public slots:
    void testDirectConnection();
    void testQueuedConnection();

    void myObjectSlot(const MyObject &obj);

};

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);

    QPushButton *b1 = new QPushButton;
    b1->setText("direct");
    layout->addWidget(b1);
    connect(b1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(testDirectConnection()));

    QPushButton *b2 = new QPushButton;
    b2->setText("queued");
    layout->addWidget(b2);
    connect(b2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(testQueuedConnection()));

    qRegisterMetaType<MyObject>("MyObject");

    connect(this, SIGNAL(myObjectSignal1(MyObject)),
            this, SLOT(myObjectSlot(MyObject)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(myObjectSignal2(MyObject)),
            this, SLOT(myObjectSlot(MyObject)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}

void Widget::testDirectConnection()
{
    MyObject obj;
    emit myObjectSignal1(obj);
}

void Widget::testQueuedConnection()
{
    MyObject obj;
    emit myObjectSignal2(obj);
}

void Widget::myObjectSlot(const MyObject &obj)
{
}
```

The `Qt::DirectConnection` scenario:

1. `myObjectSignal1` signal is connected to `myObjectSlot` using
   `Qt::DirectConnection`.
2. `MyObject` is created inside `Widget::testDirectConnection`.
3. `myObjectSignal1` signal triggers `myObjectSlot` as a normal function call.
4. `MyObject` is passed by reference into `myObjectSlot`.
5. `myObjectSlot` execution finishes.
6. `MyObject` is destroyed as control leaves `Widget::testDirectConnection`.

The output will be:

```
MyObject::MyObject() 
MyObject::~MyObject()
```

The `Qt::QueuedConnection` scenario:

1. `myObjectSignal2` signal is connected to `myObjectSlot` using
   `Qt::QueuedConnection`.
2. `MyObject` is created inside `Widget::testQueuedConnection`.
3. `myObjectSignal2` signal triggers and `MyObject` is copied into the event queue.
4. `MyObject` is destroyed as the control leaves `Widget::testQueuedConnection`.
5. Control returns to the event loop and execute `myObjectSlot` which gets a copy of `MyObject`.
6. The copy of `MyObject` is destroyed as control leaves `myObjectSlot`.

The output will be:

```
MyObject::MyObject() // object is created inside testQueuedConnection
MyObject::MyObject(const MyObject&) // object is copied
MyObject::~MyObject() // object is destroyed
MyObject::~MyObject() // copy is destroyed
```

If you want to avoid additional object copy, you can allocate memory for you data on the heap using `new` operator and then pass a pointer. But in this case you must make sure that your object is destroyed when processing is over.

A good article on arguments copying in Qt signal-slot connections: http://www.embeddeduse.com/2013/06/29/copied-or-not-copied-arguments-signals-slots/